# Weird typeloadexception "Bad flags on delegate constructor."

Tags: c#, exception

Anybody seen this exception before, Google doesn't have a single post regarding the exception.
The code that raises the error is a simple add.

```
Items.Add(item);


System.TypeLoadException: Bad flags on delegate constructor.
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.Sort()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.InsertItems(Int32 displayIndex, ListViewItem[] items, Boolean checkHosting)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewNativeItemCollection.Add(ListViewItem value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection.Add(ListViewItem value)
```

Comment: Do you have a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem? Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: This error just appeared on  computer I installed our product on. It's Win server 2003, .Net 3.5. I have never seen this error before on any other computer/net-version.

I'll see if I can make a short sample and post. But i'm pretty sure that this error depends on the computer and/or environment and not on the code itself.

Comment: what is your item object?

Any data stored within the Windows Event logs?

Comment: @ChrisBD - the item is a plain ListViewItem no inherintence. But these two were in the Event logs:

.NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting
Faulting application appname.exe, version 2.1.1.0, stamp 4be937a8, faulting module mscorwks.dll, version 2.0.50727.3603, stamp 4a7cd88e, debug? 0, fault address 0x00108b9c.


.NET Runtime
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3603 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A09795E) (80131506)


What is mscorwks.dll ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is a System.Windows.Form v2.0 bug I identified this morning (and that is fixed in System.Windows.Form v4.0).

For me it happened while my code adds an `Item` to the `ListBox` while the hosting process is shutting down. The private instance field `ListBox.listItemsArray` is null and this provokes the `NullReferenceException`. I don't know exactly why `ListBox.listItemsArray` is null, but I'd guess it is related to a handle creation problem.

For me the workaround was easy since a `try/catch` was enough because the process is shutting down anyway. You can certainly dig ino the problem with the decompiling Reflector feature as I did:

[image]

Comment: Nice, all though I switched from .Net to Java a couple of months ago, it's nice to see a solution to this. I remember the troubles I had with it.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you general advice on how to solve internal exceptions. Take tool called Reflector (google it) and get into the method `System.Windows.Forms.ListView.Sort()` and try to understand what conditions lead to exception. this helped me many times.

Comment: public void Sort()
{
    if (this.VirtualMode)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("ListViewSortNotAllowedInVirtualListView"));
    }
    this.ApplyUpdateCachedItems();
    if (base.IsHandleCreated && (this.listItemSorter != null))
    {
        NativeMethods.ListViewCompareCallback pfnCompare = new NativeMethods.ListViewCompareCallback(this.CompareFunc);
        UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef(this, base.Handle), 0x1030, IntPtr.Zero, pfnCompare);
    }
}

Been there done that, can u see the problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's a case of searching on the error number 80131506. I've found a few references:

If your application has been written using NET 2 and maybe ASP.NET, but more importantly runs under a user profile then look here:

[Microsoft hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913384)

I've also come across someone whereby SQL Developer on the server machine was causing issues:
[SQL DEvloper issues](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33880236/fatal-execution-engine-er.aspx)

There is also talk of this problem occuring on 64 bit machines [shown here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/40e8e7e7-d051-49b7-ba2c-509b210a9736). Typically involving access to memory addresses beyond 4Gb.